# How to get sound to work in HDMI

Tags: sound

I can't get sound to work on HDMI. I've read every thread on it I found, tried everything and nothing seems to work.

When I connect the HDMI cable to my tv (which btw had no problems with hdmi sound prior to this, whether with my ps4 or windows) the screen duplicates or extends to the tv randomly, which is weird but unimportant. Unlike other distros I tried where mouse started to lag, on elementary there's no issues with HDMI other than the apparent lack of sound.

I've tried downloading pavucontrol, I've tried updating alsa, I've tried every nvidia driver I found, but nothing I do changes anything in the sound options. I still only get the choice between speakers and digital s/pdif.

I'm using an older laptop with second generation i7 CPU 6gb of ram, an integrated Intel graphics card and a GT 635M.

Comment: I have the same issue. And there is no the HDMI output in profile list. Still no resolve..

Comment: I have the same issue and have tried everything here too: https://itsfoss.com/how-to-fix-no-sound-through-hdmi-in-external-monitor-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

Go to: system settings > sound. in Profile select HDMI output

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too, and thought it was related to my BIOS firmware so I updated that. Still no sound.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 and HDMI sound works. I'm guessing some package needs to be updated.